# Where is the music from the Interstellar trailer from?

Tags: soundtrack, trailers, interstellar

The trailer for the new Christopher Nolan film "Interstellar" was just released. The music used is very familiar but I cannot pin down the source. It is present throughout the whole clip, but is most familiar from time index 1:25.

[Interstellar trailer on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSWdZVtXT7E)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the track [Evey Reborn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjgTFd6XAg8) from Dario Marianelli's [soundtrack for 'V For Vendetta'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta:_Music_From_The_Motion_Picture) (the recognizable part you've pointed out appears [around 2:30](http://youtu.be/BjgTFd6XAg8?t=2m30s)).

**EDIT:** A comment has raised an interesting point (but was deleted because it was posted as an answer); There is a possible link between these 2 films: *Interstellar* was released in the U.S. on Guy Fawkes Day (November 5th).

Comment: I've seen VfV several times. No wonder it sounded so familiar.